# Seclast and colour choices on engulfing pattern script

Tags: pine-script

Why was seclast code used in this script?

Why was this coded instead of the names of the colours - #F70317 , #008600

Here is the script would the added alerts I wrote work?

Script below

```
//@version=2
study("Bullish and Bearish Engulfing")

checkingHighsAndLows(position) =>
    high >= high[position] and low <= low[position]

isBearishEngulfing(position) =>
    checkingHighsAndLows(position) and open >= close[position] and open >= open[position] and close <= open[position] and close <= close[position]

isBullishEngulfing(position) =>
    checkingHighsAndLows(position) and open <= close[position] and open <= open[position] and close >= open[position] and close >= close[position]

secLast = 1

barcolor(isBearishEngulfing(secLast)? #F70317: na)
barcolor(isBullishEngulfing(secLast)? #008600: na)

alertcondition(isBearishEngulfing(secLast), title='E Bear', message='E Bear')
alertcondition(isBullishEngulfing(secLast), title='E Bull', message='E Bull')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `secLast` is there if you want to compare the current candle with `n` candles back. In a sense that if it engulfs the candle that was formed `n` bars ago.

Not all colors are built-in variables. So, you can refer to any specific color with the hex representation like `#F70317` or you can use the `color.rgb()` in new versions of `pinescript`.

Your alert fucntions should work.